# SQL Server 2012 log shipping to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

Is there any way to take SQL Server 2012 log shipping files and upload them into Azure SQL Database. We just need the data changes and not to bothered about the recovery side of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot log ship to an Azure SQL Database, however, there are other options for getting the data up there incrementally. I've summarised them below (with links) and all of these support SQL Server 2012 and higher. You need to read through the documentation for each and decide which best suits your requirements.

[Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/replication-to-sql-database):
You can configure an Azure SQL Database as a subscriber for Transactional or Snapshot replication. This allows you to have data updated in your Azure SQL Database from an on-premise SQL Server or IaaS SQL Server VM in Azure.

[Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data):
SQL Data Sync is a utility used to synchronise data bi-directionally between Azure SQL Databases and on-premise/IaaS SQL Server instances. You can use it to distribute data between multiple Azure SQL Databases and is often used when an application's database is actually sharded across multiple Azure SQL Databases. NOTE: Does not work with Managed Instances at this stage.

[Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server):
You can leverage Azure Data Factory to move data from your on-premise/IaaS instances up to Azure SQL Databases. This works sort of like an SSIS PaaS solution so doesn't require additional infrastructure.

[SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017):
You can create packages in SQL Server Integration Services to copy data from your on-premise or IaaS instance up to Azure SQL Database. This process can be scheduled via a SQL Server Agent job to keep data in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Straight answer would be  'No'. You cannot run restore commands on Azure sql. Only way is bacpac .

Comment: Thanks for this. Would you be able to run automated incrementals using this method post the initial Extract / load?

Comment: No that will also not be possible. You can go for replication if all tables have primary keys.